# Processing: Array index out of bounds

Tags: arrays, processing, indexoutofboundsexception

I am new to processing and am creating a sketch where a 600px by 600px canvas is filled with 50px rects of a random color from my `orange[]` palette. The random formation of blocks need to be located inside of the `draw()` function in order to operate correctly with some conditionals that I will put in later.

The error that I am getting is **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12** on this line:

```
randomSize[varCreator] = sIncrement[int(random(0,sIncrement.length-1))];
```

I can't seem to figure out why this error is occurring. I have looked into related questions, and maybe its just because I am so new, but I can't figure it out:

```
int x; //x coordinate
int y; //y coordinat
int s = 50; //rect size
int wide = 600; //canvas width
int tall = 600; //canvas height
int[] sIncrement = new int[12];//{s, s*2, s*3, s*4, s*5, s*6};

//colors
int[] oranges = {
  #773600, #5f3613, #552700, #9c5215, #9c5c26
};
int[] blues = {
  #004848, #0c3939, #003333, #107979, #1e7979
};
int[] palette = oranges;//holds current color pallete

//random
int fillColor = palette[int(random(0, palette.length))]; //random starting fill color
int changeColor = palette[int(random(0, palette.length))]; //random new color
int[] randomSize = new int[sIncrement.length]; //array of lots of random s values to place newly color changed blocks


//setup
void setup(){
  size(wide, tall);
  background(255);
  noStroke();
  frameRate(24);

  /*fills sIncrement array with incrementing s values (i.e. if s = 50 then array 
   contains 50, 100, 150, etc...) from 0 to canvas width for use in a conditional statement*/
  for(int i = 0; i <= sIncrement.length-1; i++){
    sIncrement[i] = s*i;
  }

 //creates multiple randomSize variables for if() x or y == randomSize[varCreator] 
 for(int varCreator = 0; varCreator <= (width/s)+(height/s); varCreator++){
   randomSize[varCreator] = sIncrement[int(random(0,sIncrement.length-1))];
 }
}

//draw
void draw(){
  fill(fillColor); //selects random color from palette

  //draws grid colored boxes with s size
  for (y = 0; y <= height; y+= s) {
    for (x = 0; x <= width; x+= s) {
      if(x == sIncrement[randomSize[1]] && y == sIncrement[randomSize[3]]){
        fill(changeColor); //selects random color from palette
        rect(x, y, s, s);
      }

      else{
      fill(fillColor);
     // fill(palette[int(random(0, palette.length))]); //selects random color from palette
      rect(x, y, s, s);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be Java.

Comment: And even then ... I'm not sure what part of the error message that tells you exactly what the problem is ... is confusing.

Comment: @OMGPonies because thats exactly what they are!

Comment: @BrianRoach I just realized where my error lied. I have been looking at this for a very long time and apologize if I wasted a few seconds of your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing elements of the array `randomSize`. How long is this array? Let's see its declaration:

```
int[] randomSize = new int[sIncrement.length];
```

So, it's the same length as the array `sIncrement`. If we look a bit earlier:

```
int[] sIncrement = new int[12];
```

The length of `sIncrement`, and therefore the length of `randomSize` is 12.

In this code:

```
for(int varCreator = 0; varCreator <= (width/s)+(height/s); varCreator++){
    randomSize[varCreator] = sIncrement[int(random(0,sIncrement.length-1))];
}
```

The index you use to access the elements in the array `randomSize` is in the variable `varCreator`, which goes from 0 to `(width/s)+(height/s)`. Since the length of `randomSize` is 12, you can only use indexes from 0 to 11 to access elements, or you will have the error you are reporting.

So, if `(width/s)+(height/s)` should not be 12 or more. How much it is ?

That's where we are stuck, because nothing in your code tells us where `width` and `height` are declared. We only know that `s` is 50.

But you have these variables, `wide` and `tall`, each equals to 600. I'm going to take a wild guess and estimate that somewhere in your code you have `width = wide` and `height = tall`.

So `(width/s)+(height/s) = (600/50) + (600/50) = 12 + 12 = 24`

That's it. `varCreator` goes from 0 to 24 (included) and therefore you run out of bounds of the array.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed description!

Answer (score 1):

Tracing through your code you have this:

```
int[] sIncrement = new int[12];                    // sIncrement initialized with size 12
int[] randomSize = new int[sIncrement.length];     // randomSize initialized with size 12
for(... ; varCreator <= (width/s)+(height/s); ...) // varcreator <= 24!
randomSize[varCreator] = ...                       // Problem line
```

When `varcreator >= 12` you will get an array index out of bounds exception. Start there and fix up your code.